# ruamel.yaml.cmd rt breaks lists, if containing long string, or hash

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I just notices that the command line tool, called like this: "ruamel.yaml.cmd rt --save $YAML_FILE", will break lists that either contain long strings, or hashes:

Example list containing a hash:

Source:

```
telegraf::inputs:
  cpu:
    - percpu: true
      totalcpu: true
      report_active: true
```

output:

```
telegraf::inputs:
  cpu:
     - percpu: true
    totalcpu: true
    report_active: true
```

example list containing long string:

source:

```
rsyslog::config::snippets:
  00_forward:
    ensure: 'present'
    lines:
      - 'if $syslogfacility != 1 then {'
      - 'action(Name="collector-syslog" Type="omfwd" Target="%{hiera("rsyslog_server")}" Port="514" Action.ResumeInterval="5" Protocol="tcp")'
      - '}'
```

output:

```
rsyslog::config::snippets:
  00_forward:
    ensure: present
    lines:
       - if $syslogfacility != 1 then {
       - action(Name="collector-syslog" Type="omfwd" Target="%{hiera("rsyslog_server")}"
      Port="514" Action.ResumeInterval="5" Protocol="tcp")
       - '}'
```

I already created a bug report for this, but it was deleted with a comment pointing to https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html?highlight=indent#output-of-dump-as-a-string.

But I am not sure how this code snipped should help me with the command line tool.

Or is the tool deprecated, and I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

The automatic detection of the indent seems incorrect for your input, as that input is inconsistent (your mappings are indented 2 positions and your sequences 4 positions with an offset for the block sequence indicator of 2). `ruamel.yaml.cmd` as on PyPI doesn't support different indentation levels for sequences and mappings (ruamel.yaml didn't when that was written, it does now).

Apart from that you cannot set the line width for the output in `ruamel.yaml.cmd` for older versions ( before 2020-12-01), and those versions are using the default 80 characters for the wrapping.

I recommend you upgrade to 0.5.6 and use the command line options:

```
yaml rt  --indent 2 --width 1024 --save <yourfile>
```

---

<sub>The appropriate repository for `ruamel.yaml.cmd` is https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml-cmd/code/ci/default/tree/ . A bug report on `ruamel.yaml` which can only be used from a Python program, should include the minimal source code of the program that reproduces the error, and if not provided, issues will be removed as announced on its create issue page.</sub>

Comment: i give this a try. could you maybe fix the repo urls on pypi? they point to something that is not there anymore.

Comment: i tested this, and it is not doing the right thing :-/

with bsi 0, lists are not indented at all

i guess by mappings you mean type hash, and with sequences you mean type list/array?

if yes. the problem is that i have data structures that contain lists of hashes, see telegraf::inputs example from above.

they translate to [ordereddict([('percpu', True), ('totalcpu', True), ('report_active', True)])]

so it is a list of hashes. but when the lib dumps them, it gets the indention wrong.

i suspect the lib has problems dumping lists, that contain hashes.

Comment: There is now a ruamel.yaml.cmd 0.5.6 on pypi. I added a --width option to the rt command so try with `python -m ruamel.yaml.cmd rt --wdith 1024 --indent 2 --save yourfile`  ( tested with your 2nd source file for wrapping the long line)

Comment: I can dump that data structure without  a problem. ( `python -c "from ruamel.yaml import YAML; import sys;  a = {'list_of_hashes': [{'a': '1', 'b': 2, 'c': None}, {'d': '1', 'e': 2, 'f': True}, {'g': '1', 'h': 2, 'j': False}]}; YAML().dump(a, sys.stdout)"  `)

Comment: The links on PyPI have automatically updated with the new version. I had to move back from bitbucket to sourceforge, and set a forwarding link on bitbucket when I did so. Now it seems the braindead people at Bitbucket removed those links adding insult to injury

Comment: thanks for the width change. would it make sense to also break --bsi into two options, so that block and sequence indention can be set on there own?

using the lib directly, it is doing the right thing when calling "yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)"

Comment: Yes it would, but that takes more of a rewrite. `ruamel.yaml.cmd` 's origin is from before the introduction of seperate indents for mappings and sequences, and I couldn't have gotten that out so quickly. I also need to change the "guess_indent" utility function to make that destinction.